# Traefik http router basics

Tags: traefik, consul

I'm new in traefik and about to understand it basics.
I'm trying to use it with consul service discovery to balance requests between instances of simple web application. Here is my traefic config:

```
[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":8080"
    [entryPoints.traefik]
    address = ":8081"

[api]
    dashboard = true
    insecure  = true

[providers.consulCatalog]
    prefix           = "traefik"
    exposedByDefault = false

    [providers.consulCatalog.endpoint]
      address = "127.0.0.1:8500"
      scheme  = "http"
```

Web application instances are deployed via Nomad, and are available using Consul catalog. Job for my web application have following list of tags:

```
      tags = [
        "traefik.enable=true",
        "traefik.http.routers.one.rule=Path(`/myapp`)"
      ]
```

This approach works as intended. I can access instances of my app via `traefik_ip:8080/myapp`. But I'm concerned is there any way to access web application directly via port(`traefik_ip:8080`) instead of using prefix (/myapp in my case).
Please suggest what should I change to reach my goal?

I have tried to paly with routers config, but still can't get what should I change